# Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui while using pre compiled build for mingw-64

Tags: qt

I have downloaded Qt5.6 pre compiled for mingw-64 , i have create qt.conf file also to change predefined path, when using qmake its giving error as shown.
same command i am using

D:\PROGRAMS\mingwtest\mingw_test>qmake -spec D:\QT\Qt-5.6\mkspecs\win32-g++ -o M
akefile mingw_test.pro
 Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui

Comment: Official Qt installers patch the Qt binaries to change that path after the files are copied. That's because a pre-compiled copy of Qt belongs in a hard-coded path, it cannot be relocated. Are you using official installer, or are you downloading a 3rd-party build? I'm not quite sure of what `qt.conf` file you speak of: I've never had to deal with that, but perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I am downloading third party build, i got it from qt wiki

Comment: https://github.com/unisontech/qt-patcher

Comment: i have downloaded vwerion from https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit

Comment: Have you installed it in the correct hardcoded path, or patched the binaries to make them work from another path?

Comment: its a zip file i extracted it and updated all required path